# Fill array with specific numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I need to fill an array with numbers, a few examples:

- nbreParChargement = 4; For 10

  - Expected output: `$niveaux = array(4,4,2);` 4+4+2 = 10
- nbreParChargement = 6; For 14

  - Expected output: `$niveaux = array(6,6,2);` 6+6+2 = 14
- nbreParChargement = 16; For 13

  - Expected output: `$niveaux = array(13);` 13 = 13
- nbreParChargement = 4; For 30

  - Expected output: `$niveaux = array(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2);` 4+4+4+4+4+4+4+2 = 30

I tried to resolve this but I don't know the perfect solution:

```
function chargement($nbre, $nbreParChargement){

    $niveaux = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$nbre; $i++){
        $niveaux[$i] = $i + $nbreParChargement;         
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the rule for those numbers? random numbers? numbers that follow a formula?

Comment: Please remember to translate variable and function names to English, non-French speakers may have a hard time figuring out your code otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another implementation, with *two lines of code*, for php >= 5.6:

```
function chargement($nbre, $nbreParChargement){
    $niveaux = array_fill(0, floor($nbre/$nbreParChargement), $nbreParChargement);
    $niveaux[] = $nbre - array_sum($niveaux);

    return $niveaux;
}

var_dump(chargement(10, 4));
var_dump(chargement(14, 6));
var_dump(chargement(13, 16));
var_dump(chargement(30, 4));
```

[`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) fills an array with `$nbre/$nbreParChargement` entries with `$nbreParChargement`'s value. The last value are the difference between `$nbre` and the sum of the other elements, given by `$nbreParChargement * floor($nbre/$nbreParChargement)`, that will be always > 0.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FDKZI).

This work only for php >= 5.6 because `array_fill` accepts `0` as `num`  only from that version. Previously, `num` was required to be greater than zero.

So, for any version of php:

```
function chargement($nbre, $nbreParChargement){
    $niveaux = array();
    if ($n = floor($nbre/$nbreParChargement)) {
        $niveaux = array_fill(0, $n, $nbreParChargement);
    }

    $niveaux[] = $nbre - array_sum($niveaux);
    return $niveaux;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SSALP).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    function chargement($nbre, $nbreParChargement){
       $niveaux = array();
       $n=(int)($nbre/$nbreParChargement);//Calculating how many times to $nbreParChargement add number to an array.
       for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
          $niveaux[]=$nbreParChargement;//Adding $nbreParChargement  value to array
       }
       $diff=$nbre-array_sum($niveaux);//Calculating diff of given and our calculated value
       if($diff!=0){//If the diff value is >0 then adding the remaining that value to an array
          $niveaux[]=$diff;
       }
      return $niveaux; //Returning array
    }
    print_r(chargement(14,4));
```

[Output in Eval](https://eval.in/449758)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 2
)
```

Follow bellow steps to solve your problem:

1. Calculate how many times to nbreParChargement add number to an array,
2. Adding that number those many times(n) to array.
3. Calculate diff of given and our total values which are in value
4. If Diff is >0 then, that means we missed diff number, add that number to array and return.

Comment: Whats wrong in this code? :X, Give -1 then leave the comment, bellow the any ans. If you will do like this no will going to reply your problems in the feature.

Comment: @Kyll, Check the code, I given the comments for each and every line of posted code, before down voting check it once, what people are posted.

Comment: @Kyll, Added description

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
function chargement($nbre, $nbreParChargement){

    $niveaux = array(); 
    if($nbreParChargement <= $nbre) {
        $repetitionCount = floor($nbre / $nbreParChargement);
        $remainder = $nbre % $nbreParChargement;

        for($i = 0; $i < $repetitionCount; $i++){
            $niveaux[] = $nbreParChargement;
        }

        if(!empty($remainder)) {
            $niveaux[] = $remainder;
        }
    } else {
        $niveaux[] = $nbre;
    }
    return $niveaux;
}

$array = chargement(13, 16);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted when the code works for all the cases mentioned?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Understood. Fair enough. Thanks for the Info.